# How to create dynamic model and schema from client side

Tags: mongoose

I'm new to mongodb, I'm working on a small app where Im asked to allow the admin to create a dynamic model and schema so the users of the app can   See the schéma of the created model and fill in data with a form.
can someone have any idea how I'm gonna do that ?